# Determine correct RJ-45 network plug for your cable

Tags: ethernet, rj-45, hardware-selection

I want to crimp my own ethernet cables because its cheaper for me and I have a lot of long cables sitting around.

I'm currently looking into the crimper and everything I need and I wanted to know for the future if the RJ-45 network plugs are one fits all or if I need specific plugs for specific cable speeds.

So that Cat6 cables NEED Cat6 plugs or if I can just go buy Cat6 plugs and crimp them with Cat5e and Cat6?

Answer (score 2):

RJ45 plugs are universal (in size).
A difference is from UTP to STP (shielded cable). RJ45 connectors and plugs for STP have grounding.
However, crimper are the same for both types.
So the answer is no, no specifics. Just get a crimper you like and use it for 5E,6,STP or anything.

Comment: Oh wow. This was way less of an headache than I thought. Thank you !!

Comment: Yeap, some things actually are compatible in the IT world. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Speeds are normally dealt with via wire tolerances (quality of the wire, number of twists, termination, shieling to deal with cross-talk and other difficulties, etc...). As stated earlier, RJ45 is the standard and has been for a while but here's the other bonus. A lot of the time most crimpers are capable of acting of other types of cabling (such as telephone) as well.

Comment: Indeed, most also support RJ11 and RJ12 also.